# How to convert dataframe column value count into tabular format in pandas or python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, jupyter

I have value counts of a column of dataframe as:

```
TNP                 42530
TNP_CONF            40689
NON_TNP              5320
NON_TNP_CONF         3520
TNP_CONF_NOT         1841
NON_TNP_CONF_NOT     1800
```

I want this in tabular form using Pandas or Python:

```
            TNP  NON_TNP
CONF      40689     3520
CONF_NOT   1841     1800
TOTAL     42530     5320
```

How to make this and put in tabular form?

Comment: What is the name of the column you are applying `value_counts` to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.crosstab` instead of `value_counts`. You have to split names in two parts before:

```
out = df['col'].str.extract('(?P<tnp>(?:NON_)?TNP)_?(?P<cnt>.*)?').replace('', 'TOTAL')
out = pd.crosstab(df1['cnt'], df1['tnp']).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          NON_TNP    TNP
CONF         3520  40689
CONF_NOT     1800   1841
TOTAL        5320  42530
```

About the regular expression: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/599wkB/1)

[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'TNP': 42530, 'TNP_CONF': 40689,
        'NON_TNP': 5320, 'NON_TNP_CONF': 3520,
        'TNP_CONF_NOT': 1841, 'NON_TNP_CONF_NOT': 1800}
lst = np.concatenate([[name]*count for name, count in data.items()])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': lst}).sample(frac=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: @AnkitChauhan. Does it solve your problem?